# Reactivating the Camera/Microphone Allow Panel in Adobe Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, adobe, camera, microphone

When an Adobe Flash program accesses a camera or microphone in Adobe Flash, Adobe pops up a panel to the user if they want to Allow or Deny access. If the user clicks Deny, I would like to pop the same panel back up. However, trying to access a microphone or camera again doesn't seem to do it.

I know there's `Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.PRIVACY)`, but this is a slightly different popup which has a "Remember" option which I explicitly do not want.

Is there a way to repeatedly popup the Allow/Deny confirmation without the Remember option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to my knowledge.

The entire purpose behind these features is to allow the user privacy when they want it and to keep from allowing a malicious experience (infinitely popping up the security panel). The appropriate course of action should be to pop it the first time and if they deny, present an explanation for why the functionality is needed and a how to on manually re-enabling it.

Answer (score 0):

That may not be an option for you, but I think if you serve your pages from `http`, and not `https`, flash won't offer the option to remember that setting.